# proof that $x/c^x$ goes to 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Im trying to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{c^x}$ where $c>1$ is a constant goes to zero.  To show this i know i need to take some $\epsilon$ and find some $m$ such that $\forall x>m$, $|\frac{x}{c^x}|<\epsilon$.  However, im having trouble finding $m$. What is the usual way people go to find $m$?

Comment: What is $k$? Do you mean $x$?

Comment: The constant $c$ should not be small.

Comment: Sorry $c>1$ and $k$ should be $x$, just edited it

Comment: Derive numerator and denominator (L'Hôpital)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume that $c\gt 1$.  Then we are looking for the limit of $\frac{x}{e^{x\ln c}}$.

By the power series expansion for $e^t$, we have for positive $t$ that $e^t\gt 1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}\gt \frac{t^2}{2}$. Now it should not be hard to find a suitable $m$.

Comment: I think I understand it.  Now my only concern concern is that you are doing the series expansion around $t=0$ but we want to consider values as they are approaching $+\infty$, does it matter around what value of $t$ we do the expansion in? In addition, is there a particular reason we choose to use $\frac{t^2}{2}$? would choosing $t$ not work just as well?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Of course $\frac{t^2}{2}$ is an absolutely horrible lower bound for $e^t$ for large $t$, since in fact $e^t$ is enormously larger than $\frac{t^2}{2}$. But it is good enough to show that the limit is $0$. If we had $x^2$ on top instead of $x$, we would go one step further to $\frac{t^3}{3!}$ or use some other trick.

Comment: Note that if we don't want to use the series expansion, we can still prove the desired inequality $e^t\gt 1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}$ in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

First let's do the case where $x \to \infty$ along the integers. At the very beginning of a rigorous analysis course (certainly well before we define exponential function, or logarithm, or derivative, or irrational powers) we may prove **Bernoulli's inequality** by induction on $n$:
$$
(1+\delta)^n \ge 1+\delta n,\qquad\text{for }\delta>0, n \in \mathbb N .
$$
From that, we get:  for $a>1$
$$
a^n \ge (a-1)n
$$
and deduce that
$$
a^n \to \infty\qquad\text{and also that }\qquad\frac{a^n}{n} \ge (a-1).
$$  Given any $c>1$, I can write it as $c=ab$, where $a>1, b>1$. (I can do this without knowing square roots exist).  Then
$$
\frac{c^n}{n} = a^n\;\cdot\;\frac{b^n}{n} \ge a^n (b-1)
$$
But $b-1 > 1$ and $a^n \to \infty$, so we conclude $\frac{c^n}{n} \to \infty$.

[This argument is valid in an archimedian ordered field.  In particular it is valid even if irrational powers and/or square roots do not exist in the field.]

**added**
What about the case where $x \to \infty$ in the reals?  Of course we need to know advanced things like: how to define $c^x$ and what its properties are.  But then we can proceed like this.

Given $x > 2$, there is $ n  \in \mathbb N$ with $n\le x < n+1 < 2n$.  Then
$$
c^x \ge c^n
\\
x < 2n
\\
\frac{c^x}{x} \ge \frac{c^n}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{c^n}{n} .
$$
Therefore $\frac{c^x}{x} \to \infty$ also.

Comment: How do we get from $\frac{c^n}{n}$ to $\frac{x}{c^x}$?

Comment: The reciprocal of $\frac{c^n}{n}$ is $\frac{n}{c^n}$.  Therefore $\frac{n}{c^n} \to 0$.  I did not do the case of non-integer $x$, since I did not assume $c^x$ exists.  I will add it.